# Magento displays block titles (path hints), how do I shut it off?

Tags: magento, block, config, display

Why does my Magento store look like this?

[image]

It is setting the title of each div to show the path and name of each block file.

I followed a tutorial that showed me how to set certain switches under the system menu but I cannot find the tutorial or switches to undo the changes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3):

Path Hints has been set under `System=>Configuration=>Advanced=>Developer`

It can be set under the website or store scopes. (Indicated Dropdown in top left)

Set `Template Path Hints` and `Add Block Names to Hints` both to `No` and **then clear cache** so the configuration gets reread.

[image]

Comment: Super that works a treat  - I knew it was something striaght forward

Comment: Maybe this should be in the Magento sub domain :)